# SQLite removes ties in group by

Tags: sql, r, sqlite, sqldf

I am expecting the following to yield more than 3 rows, since there are ties of min(a.[Sepal.Width]) within each of a.[Species], 
however only 3 rows are returned:

```
sqldf(' select a.[Species], min( a.[Petal.Width]) from iris a group by a.[Species] ')
     Species min( a.[Petal.Width])
1     setosa                   0.1
2 versicolor                   1.0
3  virginica                   1.4
```

- 1: Is this normal behavior of SQLite?
- 2: How do I design a select string to also return the ties?
  (preferably as close to the original search string as possible)

Edit: I see now that my confusion stemmed from being used to using SAS proc sql, which would return all matching rows. I have now learned that this is indeed peculiar to SAS proc SQL and not to be expected from other SQL incarnations. People with the same SAS-induced confusion as me will benefit from this answer which articulate this SAS behavior: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25539916/1831980

Comment: You are confused.  I am confused.  What would the value of the *maximum* have to do with a query on the *minimum*?  And, a `GROUP BY` query returns one row per group.  Period.  One row per group.

Comment: Yes, with  `group by` it will return one row for each group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

```
sqldf::sqldf('SELECT b.[Species], b.[Petal.Width] FROM iris b JOIN
             (SELECT [Species], MIN( [Petal.Width]) AS [Petal.Width] 
              FROM iris GROUP BY [Species]) a 
             USING ([Species],[Petal.Width])')
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is what you want:

```
select i.*
from iris i
where i.sepal_width = (select max(i2.sepal_width)
                       from iris i2
                       where i2.species = i.species
                      );
```